# Vue 3 Router optional segment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I know it's possible to include optional parameters to a route via `:id?` syntax.
My question is: is it possible to include optional segments/prefixes before those optional parameters?

What I mean is the following: I would like to have a path like this:

```JS
{
    path: 'project/:projectId/variant/:variantId?/tab/:tabId?/group/:groupId?'
}
```

So in the end, I want to create routes like

```
project/5/variant/3
project/5/variant/3/tab/8
project/5/variant/3/tab/8/group/4
```

instead I currently get

```
project/5/variant/4/tab/group
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve this without different routes/components?

Comment: If your route doesn't grow beyond the one you specified, you can create 3 different routes using the same component.

Comment: I also thought about that but these must have different names and I would prefer to use only one route name instead of different one

Comment: See this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns . I guess you need to dig into path-to-regexp. Not sure if it's possible with the syntax you expect. You didn't mention the version. I'm not sure https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#repeatable-params is available in Vue 2

Comment: I already saw that but I'm not quite sure how to apply those without "hacks" to my logic. Of course I could parse the parameters  by myself but that's not quite what I want (otherwise I would have already done that before writing here) I'm using Vue 3 with the latest Router version